# How to search the Windows 8 contacts from .Net?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, .net-4.5

I'm doing estimates for a Windows 8 app, and I would like to programatically search the Windows 8 contacts store for a person's name based on their phone number or email address.  Is this possible in WinRT/.Net? I can't seem to find documentation for an API to do this.

Comment: Win RT you can't code for AFAIK

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that per se.  If you want to access the contacts locally, you have to use the [Contact Picker Contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj153343).  That will bring up the People hub and let the user select one or more contacts that you can then operate on.  If you want to search the user's contacts, you have to use the [Live Connect APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live//default.aspx).  Check out the [Interactive SDK](http://isdk.dev.live.com/ISDK.aspx) and [this video from Build](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/APP-784T).

Comment: So... I can't find a way to search for a contact by phone number. Can someone provide an example or verify if this is even possible?

Comment: Based on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243646.aspx) it seems the only phone number I can read from the Live API is the local user's number. Whoop dee doo. I can't do a reverse lookup?!